# PHP: Print ordered array

Tags: php, html

I have a simple PHP code where values from the array are ordered from **largest to lowest**.

I need them to **print** like basic HTML values with loop.

**MY CODE:**

```
$kosik = [
    [
      "typ" => "ovocna",
      "amount" => $ovocnaNUM
    ],
    [
      "typ" => "slana",
      "amount" => $slanaNUM,
    ],
    [
      "typ" => "sladka",
      "amount" => $sladkaNUM
    ]
];

usort($kosik, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b["amount"] - $a["amount"];
});
```

I need to echo them but when I use this I'ev got **error**:

```
foreach($kosik as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key - $value <br>";
}
```

**ERROR:** Array to string conversion

But when I use this:

```
foreach($kosik[0] as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key - $value <br>";
}
```

I've got no errors but only the first value is printed.

Is there any option how I can **print all values with foreach or loop** like is printed one value in code above?

Comment: Try to dump `$value` - you have a nested array. Loop over `$kosik` first, and within that loop, use another loop

Comment: You cannot echo an array, as you have an array of arrays, `$value` will also be an array

Comment: @NicoHaase like this? 
foreach($value as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key - $value <br>";
    }
}

Comment: @RiggsFolly and how I can echo this array?

Comment: Are you looking for something like : `foreach($kosik as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['typ'].' - '.$value['amount'];
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, simply address the $value array using its members

```
foreach($kosik as $key => $value) { 
    echo "$key - $value[typ], $value[amount] <br>";  
}
```

> NOTE that inside a double quoted string you address the array slightly differently, you dont use the quotes around the occurance name.

Possibly more flexibly you could use a double loop, specially if you dont know or cannot guarantee the occurances will always be there

```
$str = '';
foreach($kosik as $key => $value) { 
    $str .= "$key - ";
    foreach ( $value as $val ) {
        $str .= "$val, ";
    }
    $str = rtrim($str, ', ');  remove trailing comma
    $str .= '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of your script :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [typ] => ovocna [amount] => ) [1] => Array ( [typ] => slana [amount] => ) [2] => Array ( [typ] => sladka [amount] => ) )
```

The error is that the $value you use in the foreach loop is an array so you can't use the echo function.
To access the value of 'typ' and 'amount' you must use the following form $value ['typ'] and $value ['amount'].